# Always check Network Reachability in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, reachability, runloop

I'd like to know if what would be the best way to ALWAYS check if the app is connected to the network?

Say, have it scheduled to check every 10seconds.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SystemConfiguration` framework to monitor the network state. Take a look at [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) example. Check the connection before initiating an operation that requires a working internet connection.